# Installing PyGame, difference between Python2.7 and 3.4?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pygame, pip

I would like to work with the PyGame module and, naturally, went about installing it. Since the default version of python is 2.7, I downloaded (much earlier) python 3.4 and have been using it forever now. When installing PyGame, I enter the following commands into Terminal: `python3.4 -m pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame`

As you might see, I am using `pip` and `mercurial` to my aid here.

When trying to install PyGame with the commands above, the installation seems to begin but returns the following errors:

```
WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "config.py"
Using Darwin configuration...

/bin/sh: smpeg-config: command not found
/bin/sh: smpeg-config: command not found
/bin/sh: smpeg-config: command not found
/bin/sh: /usr/X11R6/bin/freetype-config: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: /usr/X11R6/bin/freetype-config: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: /usr/X11R6/bin/freetype-config: No such file or directory
WARNING: "smpeg-config" failed!
WARNING: "/usr/X11R6/bin/freetype-config" failed!
Hunting dependencies...
SDL     : found 1.2.15
Framework SDL not found
FONT    : found
Framework SDL_ttf not found
IMAGE   : found
Framework SDL_image not found
MIXER   : found
Framework SDL_mixer not found
SMPEG   : not found
Framework smpeg not found
Framework CoreMIDI found
Framework QuickTime found
PNG     : found
JPEG    : found
PORTMIDI: found
FREETYPE: not found
AVFORMAT: not found
SWSCALE : not found

If you get compiler errors during install, doublecheck
the compiler flags in the "Setup" file.


Continuing With "setup.py"
Skipping module _numericsurfarray for Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  5 2014, 20:42:22)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] build.
Skipping module _numericsndarray for Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  5 2014, 20:42:22)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] build.

no previously-included directories found matching '*/CVS'
no previously-included directories found matching '*/*/CVS'
```

I have previously installed the dependencies through terminal, but can it be that they installed for python 2.7 only and python3.4 doesn't recognize them? (I don't know if this is a valid suggestion, as this type of stuff isn't my area of expertise)

I went into Python3.4 (interactive mode) and importing PyGame worked (but I imagine I won't be able to use all of the module's functions).

However, when I run the same command on terminal with the default python (2.7), it installs successfully:

```
    sudo pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
Password:
Collecting hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
  Cloning hg http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame to /tmp/pip-q1scmd-build
Installing collected packages: pygame
  Running setup.py install for pygame
Successfully installed pygame-1.9.2a0
```

Can someone suggest a reason for the difference? I suppose I can work with python2.7 when making games, but it is still tedious to have to switch between two versions of the same language.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=33157

```
<pre>

$ sudo apt-get install mercurial 
$ hg clone https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
$ cd pygame

$ sudo apt-get install libsdl-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev 
$ sudo apt-get install libsmpeg-dev libportmidi-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev
$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-numpy

$ python3 setup.py build 
$ sudo python3 setup.py install

</pre>
```